# Codeigniter-4 redirect back and ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this issue without manually modifying CI core code.

CI4 saves a reference to the last requested url so it can do it's redirect()->back() function however when you use ajax it stores that call and when I want to use back on the next page (say a link clicked from the current page) it tries to redirect me back to the ajax page and not the main page.

CI's function that handles this is in **system/Codeigniter.php** (*line 969 on my version*) **public function storePreviousURL($uri)**

I can add an exception inside of this to ignore url's with ajax in the name however I am editing code I shouldn't be touching because it will get overwritten during updates. I am not sure how to intercept this and make changes from the outside. I am not sure how to override this class since it's a level above the core classes that you can extend and override.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you look at the same file in CI 4.0.3 LINE 1048 it has provision for ignoring AJAX requests. As our line numbers differ it would appear you are using an older version. So give that a try.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Ah thank you I did a composer update but it didn't update my code said it was up-to-date already but I did a manual copy/paste update of the files and that fixed it.